# How to create a list add GameObjects to it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an `OnTriggerEnter`, and when a `GameObject` (player) enters this trigger, I would like for it to be added to a list and then access the position of the player in that list later on.

I know how to detect when the player has entered the trigger, but I am not sure how to make the list and automatically add the player to it.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you show us some code?

Comment: Have you tried google, this is a pretty basic question. An attempt at the code would render better answers for you. http://www.dotnetperls.com/list

Comment: `new List<GameObject>()`

Answer (score 0):

You can create list as a property of that game object with trigger. In that case you have:

```
public class TriggerObject : MonoBehaviour {

     List<GameObject>() EnteredPlayers = new List<GameObject>();

     void OnTriggerEnter(Collider player) {
          EnteredPlayers.Add(player.gameObject);
     }     
}
```

I'd suggest to use singleton to store that list, but it definitely depends on your project architecture.